# What are these yellow parts that look like capacitors?

Tags: identification, components

What are these components? They seem to be the same thing, but one has 2 and the other 3 pins.

[image]

Comment: In-focus, cropped photo, please. About 90% of that photo is background.

Comment: Yes, they are pretty small and this is the best I could do with my iphone… closer it was too blurry…

Comment: Move out until in focus, take photo and then crop it. Anyway it seems you got an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Piezoelectric filters (resonators). These - per marking - are 10.7MHz band pass filters used for FM intermediate frequency (IF) in a typical superherherodyne FM radio receiver.

The middle terminal - if present - is a ground connection.

[Ceramic resonator (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_resonator)

Answer (score 0):

That's a ceramic resonator. It has a ceramic piezoelectric crystal inside, and the left one has capacitors to ground.